# Non admin login for facebook android application (sandbox mode disbaled)

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I have been trying to use facebook login for my android application.

1. I made sandbox mode disabled from the beginning of the application.
2. Key hashes are generated.
3. App Id, facebook login are enabled.

But my problem is I can only access via admin account, but not from any other account. Each time I am trying to login using non-admin accounts, my session state is found to be closed.

Comment: try clearing data on device